# Service Fabric 0x80004005 Access denied Open up port for HttpListener

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am facing the following error message in my local (development) service fabric instance:

```
2016-09-20 12:56:16.5008 WARN   7  Metrics.Visualization.MetricsHttpListener Unable to start HTTP Listener. Sleeping for 1 sec and retrying 2 more times System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Metrics.Visualization.MetricsHttpListener.Start() in C:\Work\Metrics.NET\Src\Metrics\Visualization\MetricsHttpListener.cs:line 97
   at Metrics.Visualization.MetricsHttpListener.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<<StartHttpListenerAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Work\Metrics.NET\Src\Metrics\Visualization\MetricsHttpListener.cs:line 62
```

Metrics.Net is trying to open a port. Obviously that fails. I wonder how I can fix this issue.

To my ServiceManifest.xml I added the following line:

```
 <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
           listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
           replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
      <Endpoint Name="MyApplicationTypeEndpoint" Protocol="http" Port="20002" />
    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
```

Port is correct.

**Is there anything else I should take care of?**
(Also on a side note - how can I open up port ranges instead of single ports?)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the URL you're adding to the HttpListener Url Prefix is using the port defined in ServiceManifest.xml?

"Access denied" either means:

1. Someone else is already using that port
2. You are not using the port that you set up in ServiceManifest.xml

You can already use any port from the application port range. That range is a set of ports in the high-port-number range that Service Fabric opens through the OS firewall. Those ports come from the same pool of application ports that the TCP/IP stack gives you when you open a socket on port 0. Or, if you set up an Endpoint config in ServiceManifest.xml and **don't** specify a port number there, you'll get a random port from this range.

The ports you defined in ServiceManifest.xml are mainly for http.sys URL ACLing. It will also open a port through the OS firewall if it is a port outside of the application port range.

"Opening" the ports to the Internet through a load balancer is a different story and isn't really related to Service Fabric. That's more of a hardware/topology configuration (Service Fabric is all software). In Azure you can configure that through your cluster's Resource Manager JSON, or even through the Azure portal when you're creating a cluster.

The application port range is defined per node in your cluster (or per VMSS in Azure).

Comment: clear explanation. What if the guest executable want to listen to the same port in servicemanifest? Is the 'someone else' servicemanifest? otherwise how would the external request reach the executable?